# Why do C++ classes not have access specifiers like classes in Java have?

Tags: c++, class, privileges

I'm new to C++, and I'm familiar with Java. The first thing I was wondering about when I started looking at C++ code is that classes themselves (not the members) don't have access specifiers such `private`, `protected` and `public`.  Exemples [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2).

```
public class A { // This line.
  private class B { } // Not this line.
}
```

Why is that so?

Comment: You haven't looked hard enough. C++ **does** have class access modifiers.

Comment: In your examples it contains privilege definitions even...

Comment: You can do exactly what your edit states in C++ using `private`:  `public class A{ private: class B{}; };`.  The `private:` is optional since everything defaults to private.  It might be good to investigate the language more before making assumptions about what it cannot do.

Comment: With the Modules TS (technical specification), similar functionality may become available in C++ in the future, albeit with exported classes prefixed by `export` instead of `public`.  From what I understand, modules provide rough equivalents of `public` classes (`export`ed classes and functions) and package-private classes (classes and functions which aren't `export`ed).  Note that to my knowledge, `protected` members still aren't accessible to the entire module, unlike Java `protected` members and their packages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no access modifier at the level of classes, since the language has no concept of **package**. But there is at the level of data members, member functions and inheritence:

```
class Foo {};
class Bar : public Foo {

 public:
  void bar() const {}
 private:
  int bar_(float) {}
  int a, b, c;

};
```

The closest you can get is declaring nested classes inside a class:

```
class Foo {

  struct Bar0 {
    void bar0() const {}
  };
  struct Bar1 {
    Bar0 b0;
    Bar1() { b0.bar0();}
  };

};
```

Comment: @OfekRon that is as difficult as answering "why does java have access control at the level of classes". It doesn't mean much without the concept of package, or a set of entities which have access to a private class. C++ never had this concept, and I guess it has never been deemed necessary to introduce it. In the end, it is a design decision.

Comment: @OfekRon: In Java, all classes are in packages, and making them private means they can only be used only in the package.  In C++, classes are by default in the _global_ namespace.  public/private in the global namespace makes no sense.  If you move them to _any other namespace_ you can mark them as private/public.

Comment: @MooingDuck That is a good answer, you should post it and i will accept it

Comment: One should note that a commonly used pattern (e.g by some boost libraries) is to declare a "internal" namespace containing classes which are intended to be used by the library itself (as equivalent to the private access modifier at class level).

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for class-level access specifier. If you want a `private` class, you can define it in an implementation file or an anonymous `namespace`. This sort of restriction is done at file-level for C++ (i.e. how you organize your headers, preprocessor directives).

Before edit:

They do, but they're not *per-method*. Also, classes have a default `private` specifier, so, unless otherwise noted, they are `private`.

```
class A
{
   void foo(); //private
};
class B
{
   void foo();  //private
public:
   void foo1(); //public
   void foo2(); //public
protected:
   void foo3(); //protected
private:
   void foo4(); //private
};
```

**Note 1** C++ also has `struct`, which is identical to a `class` except the default access level is `public`.

**Note 2** There is no *package-scope* in C++. In Java, `protected` gives access to the whole package, in C++ it just gives access to deriving classes.

**Note 3** The `friend` keyword can be used to bypass restrictions, look it up.

Comment: Perhaps `struct` is worth mentioning?

Comment: A `struct` is just a `class` that defaults to `public` instead of `private`.

Comment: @StevenBurnap, that's what I meant, and it's there now, so it's all good.

Comment: @OfekRon actually, you didn't phrase the question properly.

Comment: @OfekRon You shouldn't downvote someone for answering a silly question accurately just because you didn't phrase it correctly. You're lucky anyone answered at all.

Comment: Classes *can* be public/private/protected.

Comment: @meagar that's just an inner class. Its purpose isn't to provide the functionality Java does.

Comment: I dont think that one can say "there is no need".If you define it in a annomynous namespace you not just get a odd project structure (class in function???) the class will also be just useable in a implementation.Other classes cant actually use it (e.g as member) if they dont want to be private too.Defining the class in a implementation brings the above restrictions too (with the only exception that you can use it in multiple classes more easily).What i want to make clear is that packages have their use and c++ cannot really compensate their lack.I dont want to fight a java vs c++ discussion.

Comment: @Paranaix yes, I agree, what I meant was that the same effect can be achieved through other means. Java distributes packages, C++ can have private headers - so no code duplication. You can just build a module and not supply the headers of the classes you want to keep private. Or not export them.

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses a slightly different syntax where access modifiers are specified for groups of declarations instead of individually:

```
class Test {
  class MyPrivateClass {
    // ...
  };

  void privateByDefault();

public:
  void myPublicFunction();
  void anotherPublicFunction();

private:
  void myPrivateFunction();

public:
  class MyPublicClass {
    // ...
  };

  void morePublicFunctions();

protected:
  // ...
};
```

`Test::MyPrivateClass` is inaccessible outside of `Test`, while `Test::MyPublicClass` can be used anywhere.

Comment: He's talking about the modifier on the actual _class_ at file scope.

Answer (score -1):

From your source: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes

> private members of a class are accessible only from within other
>   members of the same class or from their friends. protected members are
>   accessible from members of their same class and from their friends,
>   but also from members of their derived classes. Finally, public
>   members are accessible from anywhere where the object is visible.

Comment: Question is about the class visibility, not the member's visibility.